# No llego a entender una parte de este programa en NASM

Tags: nasm, assembly, asm

estaba leyendo el libro de ensamblador de Paul Carter y de ahí saque este código, mi duda es, en la línea 33 se muestra una instrucción que almacena la dirección de memoria de esa línea y le suma 7 bytes para ir a la línea 36, pero según entiendo se estaría trabajando en NASM de 32 bits y para saltar dos instrucciones se debería saltar 8 bytes, dado que cada instrucción ocuparía 4 bytes (32 bits).

¿Alguien me puede explicar porque se suman 7 y no 8 en esa instrucción? (El código funciona bien).

Gracias de antemano, saludos.

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

segment .data
  
  prompt1 db  "Ingrese un numero: ", 0
  prompt2 db  "Ingrese otro numero: ", 0
  outmsg1 db  "Ud. ha ingresado ", 0
  outmsg2 db  " y ",0
  outmsg3 db  ", la suma de ellos es ", 0
  
segment .bss
  input1 resd 1
  input2 resd 1
  
segment .text
  global _asm_main

_asm_main:
  enter 0, 0
  pusha
  mov eax, prompt1
  call print_string
  mov ebx, input1
  mov ecx, ret1
  jmp short get_int

ret1:
  mov eax, prompt2
  call print_string
  
  mov ebx, input2
  mov ecx, $ + 7  ;<--- Línea 33
  jmp short get_int
  
  mov eax, [input1] ; <--- Línea 36
  add eax, [input2]
  mov ebx, eax
  
  mov eax, outmsg1
  call    print_string
  mov eax, [input1]
  call    print_int
  mov eax, outmsg2
  call print_string
  mov eax, [input2]
  call print_int
  mov eax, outmsg3
  call print_string
  mov eax, ebx
  call print_int
  call print_nl
  
  popa
  mov eax, 0
  leave
  ret
  
  get_int:
    call read_int
    mov [ebx], eax
    jmp ecx
```

Answer (score 2):

Cada instrucción del intel 80x86 tiene un tamaño. No todas son de 4 bytes por estar en modo 32 bits.

Si ejecutas *nasm* añadiendo la opción `-l fichero.lst` te generara un *fichero.lst* con el código maquina que genera el ensamblador, en este caso:

```
...
33 0000002A B9[31000000]              mov ecx, $ + 7  ;<--- Linea 33
34 0000002F EB57                      jmp short get_int
35                                    
36 00000031 A1[00000000]              mov eax, [input1] ; <--- Linea 36
...
```

Donde puedes ver que el `mov ecx, $ + 7` ocupa 5 bytes y el `jmp short get_int` 2 bytes.

En el libro veo que se asume que todos sus ejemplos corren en segmentos de 32bits. Eso también determina el tamaño de las instrucciones.

Existen segmentos(o secciones) de código de 16bits, de 32bits y de 64bits en procesadores de 64bits.
Los de 16bits(para ejecutar instrucciones del intel 8086,80186,80286) también pueden ejecutar código de 32bits; algunas instrucciones añaden prefijos al código de la instrucción para indicar que son de 32bits. Estos prefijos añaden 1 byte más.
En el caso de segmentos de 32 bits con instrucciones de 16bits pasa lo mismo pero al revés, algunas instrucciones de 16 bits necesitan el prefijo. Todo esto complica la codificación de instrucciones.

Saludos.